# GDM Login screen Glitch

Tags: gdm

I tried to change the log in screen background of Ubuntu 19.10. I did the following modification in gdm3.css.

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/thumb-1920-606500.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center; }
```

And I am quiet satisfied with the result. Now I have several minor glitches too.

At first login System freezes for around 2 secs with a black screen then the pinkish noise-texture screen flashes then everything goes to normal.

Second problem is that during a login session whenever for the 1st time I lock the system using super+L, the login screen is set to the grey version of noise-texture.png. After logging in for all the next instance locking the system produces expected screen(my customized one i.e " url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/thumb-1920-606500.jpg)) ".

How to get rid of these 2 problems?

Comment: Hello Pratap! when I for the first time locks the screen using super+L or through mannual click whatever, the grey color screen appears (which I don't expect). Afterwards without (shutting down the system) whenever I locks the screen expected pic(that i changed in gdm3.css) comes. I don't want that grey screen at all not even for once. can you share me your mail id or by whatever means I can share you the exact clip recorded via phone. Everything happens within 10 sec.

Comment: Hello Pratap please find the video here <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A80QUw4sa7H4nl1vq1mZDpXPjIKjcZdS/view?usp=sharing> both the purple screen and gray screen is here can you help me to get rid of both of them please watch it completely

Comment: I have the only admin user lemme try with the creating new user. Btw thx for the watching and staying tuned with me. I appreciate and forgimme for being a nuisance. Hopefully I would get a solution for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106388/discussion-between-pratap-and-sabyasachi-rout).

Comment: Hey pratap check the chat and how to use gnome-session should I just install it or what to turn that purple flash to grey?

Comment: gnome-session package u need to install n choose the session at login screen...